# "Lady, my need is upon me."

Tags: story-identification, sword-and-sorcery

I'm remembering a scene from a fantasy book I read sometime, I think, in the 80s. I thought it was a swords and sorcery novel, but it could be high fantasy.

I remember an encounter between the hero and a woman, where the hero utters something very like "Lady, my need is upon me" to romantically and seductively suggest they get it on. My memory suggests she says yes, and that they end up married. I think the scene was in castle (possibly her father's?) and it was night.

I *thought* it was Dorian Hawkmoon speaking to Yisselda in Michael Moorcock's Runestaff books. But I've just re-read that series and it wasn't there.

I still think it's most likely Moorcock but a quick flick through a few Corum and Elric books couldn't locate the scene. Other candidate authors I read at the time include Robert E Howard, Raymond Feist, Stephen Donaldson, Patricia McKillip and Sheri Tepper. However it doesn't feel right for any of those authors.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's from that literary masterwork [the Gor series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41821-gor). Specifically [Beasts of Gor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8705833):

> “Forgive me, Lady,” said I, “but my need is much upon me.”
>
> The two slave girls, bare-armed and veiled, quickly glanced to one another.
>
> “I do not understand,” said the graceful figure in the sedan chair. She was free.
>
> I grinned at her. “I have food,” I said. “I have water. But I have not had for four days a woman.”

Norman uses variants of this phrase a lot in the Gor series, uttered both by men and women. From a quick search this seemed the closest to the wording you remember but it didn't happen in the lady's (Lady Constance) castle. You may have remembered one of the other variants of the phrase in the series.

Comment: literary masterwork :-)

Comment: Egad, that must be it. At least I remembered how romantic and seductive the line was. Now that you've ID'd it, I shall never read it again!

Comment: And I owe Michael Moorcock an apology for confusing his works with Gor.

Comment: Especially in the later books, there were story arcs which could have made one good novel IF he had left out all the philosophy. The 3 Jason Marshall stories, for example.

Comment: I mean..."Moorcock's Runestaff"...one could be forgiven for assuming such a line must be in there.

Comment: @FlaStorm32, I agree. If you took the S&M philosophy out of the 3 Jason Marshall books, you'd only have enough material left over for one book.

Comment: I read the words "from that literary masterwork" . . . and then I read "the Gor Series" . . . and I couldn't hold back the laughter. Really! (Not that I tried very hard to hold it back, but the point is that it was a spontaneous and very audible outburst, and I just thought you might like to know.)